# Does Android assume that any timestamps I want to display to the user are in UTC and it will display it in the phones native time zone for me?

Tags: android, timezone, timestamp

Just want to confirm how I should be displaying time stamps to users.
We store our system timestamps in UTC, such as submitted dates, and time stamps and when certain actions or events occur etc.

I'm doing some tests right now. I do a query and get a list of UTC timestamps back as strings and then I want to get it into a Calendar form. I'm doing this:

```
someTimeStamp = Calendar.getInstance();
long l = Long.valueOf(stringTimeStampFromDBViaJson);
someTimeStamp.setTimeInMillis(l);
```

The values I get back from the DB in UTC for example are

```
2012-09-18 19:36:23.950
2012-09-18 19:31:55.193
```

So my phone being in EST, is displaying them as the following straight up

```
18 September, 2012 03:36:23 PM
18 September, 2012 03:31:55 PM
```

Which is what I want. I'm just wondering if this is the behaviour I can count on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly define otherwise, all Java stamps represent UTC time and date since the Unix epoch (Jan 1 1970).  If you use System calls (i.e. Android/Google library API calls) then you need to know if these are local or UTC but it's usually easy to tell from the API prototype and, in my experience, is "sufficiently" documented.

I'm working on a project right now which has to mix UTC, GMT and local and all of my stamps are internally presented as milliseconds UTC since the epoch.  Only when I display to the user do I take timezones into account.  I use the Calendar class exclusively for representing DTGs and for calculations and have found it both accurate and reliable.

I also have a helper class which contains methods such as

```
long startOfDayUsingPrefs(long millis)
```

and

```
long startOfDay(long millis).
```

The former returns the timestamp for the first tick since midnight today UTC or local time, depending on a preference the user sets (use local timezone or UTC).  The latter is always UTC.

Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks for the reply, i was trying to do something similar, have a local method that attempts to convert the UTC timestamp I get from the DB to some users preference. it wasn't always doing what I expected. in my example, i simply create a calendar object from the milliseconds I get from a JSON object and what gets displayed seems to have undergone some conversion. therefore I seem to think i don't need the usingPrefs method.... but you seem to think you do?

Comment: I'm not sure that I said you do need it ;)  The reason I need it is that a lot my internal calculations are based on the current UTC day.  I have the time for "now" from the local system which is always UTC but, I need to know when the day starts both UTC and locally.  When I use the Calendar class, I only ever set it using setTimeInMillis.  The Calendar class will always use UTC unless you specify a timezone, which I never do.  The ONLY time I don't use UTC is when I display to the user which is where startOfDayUsingPrefs comes into it.  Good luck.